# Vhdl Stack Trace

Tags: vhdl

Is it possible to get the stack trace info in VHDL? Just like in Java or something similar:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

If there is a way, then how to print it to a file not to the console?

Comment: That's not a function of the language but of the tools. Check your simulator's documentation (stack trace makes no sense for synthesis!)

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond for the reply, actually i am new to vhdl and i need something independent of tools so i don't know if there are some libraries could do that or not (i already searched but did't find something useful). and yes 'make no sense for synthesis' ,but  i need it only for the purpose of collecting the stack info that is why i need to print them to file.

Comment: Since it's a function of the tools and your unstated requirement is for tool independence, that makes the answer a lot simpler : No.

Comment: Tools implementing [VHDL-2017](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/VHDL2017) will offer a similar feature named: [Call Path](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/LCS2016_015)

Comment: thanks @Paebbels for reply, it seems that i have to use a tool for a that, then can i use "report  "message"  " for example to print the file name and line executed ? and how to direct the output of the report to a file?

Comment: This depends on your simulator. Some can redirect messages to a transcript file. You can also use frameworks like [OSVVM](https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM) to replace VHDL assert and report statements with more powerful VHDL subprograms to directly write and organize logging/assertion messages.

Comment: @Paebbels thanks this helps a lot.

Comment: [VUnit](http://vunit.github.io) has a [logging library](http://vunit.github.io/logging/user_guide.html) that can add file name and line number to all your log entries. Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a location of an entity using the predefined entity attribute PATH_NAME. For example

```
architecture rtl of ent is

begin

  assert(FALSE)
  report "Entity path = "&ent'path_name
  severity NOTE;

end architecture;
```

Unfortunately this will not work from a package when there is no entity.

Comment: INFO isn't a value of type SEVERITY_LEVEL (while NOTE is). The position in a design hierarchy provided by predefined attribute PATH_NAME isn't useful in tracing subprogram execution. However -2019 (when implemented) will provide a function GET_CALL_PATH that will provide a call trace when invoked in a subprogram which is useful considering operator overloads are defined in functions and long chains of subprogram are common. Otherwise there are debuggers for simulator execution issues or waveform dumps for design specification issues.

Comment: @user16145658. Thanks for the bug pickup and your comment is 100% correct. I have found the path_name to be useful in some situations so I thought it would be worth mentioning here even if isn't a full solution.